# Unable to Read Outlook Mails by applying filter on sender using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook

Below is the code I used

```
import win32com.client
import os
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) #Inbox default index value is 6
message=inbox.Items
get_path = os.getcwd()
message2=message.GetLast()
subject=message2.Subject
body=message2.body
date=message2.senton.date()
sender=message2.Sender
attachments=message2.Attachments
for m in message:
    if m.sender=='ritwikvijayan@gmail.com':# here in my requirement i will change the dates
        print(m.SentOn.strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S"))
        for x in m.Attachments:
            x.SaveASFile(os.path.join(get_path,x.FileName))
            print ("successfully downloaded attachments")
```

I am getting this error: AttributeError: .sender

Comment: Please provide the entire error output. Have you done any debugging? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

`MailItem.Sender` returns an [AddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry) object, not a string. You can use its Name and Address properties.

Also keep in mind `Items.GetLast` does not return the last item you are seeing in Outlook. Unless the Items collection is explicitly sorted, what you get back is undetermined. Most likely you will get the older created object in that folder.